# Corrigindo erro ao iniciar novo projeto ionic

Tags: angular, ionic

Estou tentando criar um novo app IONIC mas sempre que escolho o Angular ele me retorna esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então Matheus, já responderam isso varias vezes e acho que você não procurou muito antes de fazer essa pergunta e é até que bem simples de resolver esse erro.

---

Desinstala o ionic com esse comando

```
npm uninstall -g --save ionic
```

depois limpa o cache (se não der certo coloca o **--force**)

```
  npm cache clean (--force)
```

e instala ele globalmente

```
 npm install -g ionic
```